# Upper bounding Lipschitz constant of differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let's assume we have a k-differentiable function with an unknown Lipschitz constant, $f:\mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$.

How can we upper bound $Lip(f)$? Can we somehow use that Jacobian or Hessian to bound it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes : on a convex set $C$, you know that if the norm of the Jacobian (seen as a linear application) is bounded by $k$ on this convex set, then, for all $x,y\in C$
$$ \|f(a)-f(b)\|\leq k\|a-b\|$$
If $C$ is the whole space, you have an upper bound for  Lip($f$).

Comment: What if it is not convex?

Comment: @FrancoisWassert It may not be true... But the whole space $\mathbb{R}_m$ is convex, so it is not a problem in your case.

Comment: oh I see. So we don't need convexity in $f$ but convexity in domain?

Comment: @FrancoisWassert Exactly, it is all about the shape of the domain (for example a nice ball ; if you have something in "U" shape, you can imagine some counter example where the variation of the differential is regular and slow, but the value of the function at both ends of the domain may be really far from each other (imagine descending a road in that shape on the side of a mountain).

Comment: That's a great intuitive example. Could you explain more what type of norm is necessary? Can any norm be used? Could you please expand a little bit more on your answer :)

Comment: @FrancoisWassert you need to use the norm of the linear applications : $||| u ||| :=\sup_{\|x\|\leq 1} \| ux\|$ . If you use a different norm, it may not be true (you can for example multiply this norm by any constant, it will give you another norm with a different bounding value) ; so from the Jacobian matrix $J(a)$ (at some point $a$) you need to compute $m_a =\sup_{\|x\|\leq 1} \|J(a)x\|$ and find $M:=\sup_{a\in \mathbb{R}^m}m_a$. If $M< \infty$, you can conclude that $f$ is at least $M$-Lipschitz.